# Can you freeze food with cream in it?

Tags: freezing, cream

I have been told that you can't freeze meals with cream in them (soups, etc). Is that true?

Comment: Do you have a link to this advice? Basically, cream alone doesn't freeze well, but combined in a finished dish it's just fine. See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5864/can-you-freeze-bagna-cauda-cream-basically?r=SearchResults&s=4|38.5341 [pddly, the answer doesn't answer the asked question… but it does answer yours ;))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you freeze bagna cauda? (cream basically)](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5864/can-you-freeze-bagna-cauda-cream-basically)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's safe to do, it's just a quality issue. The cream or milk may "break" once thawed, which could ruin the textures or cohesiveness of the dish.  But it's not such a big deal if the dish is smooth and homogenous to start with, as you can just whisk it back together.

In the winters, we make large batches of soups that call for cream, but we omit the cream and add it back in when it's serving time.